# Is mediator-js realtime? How can I add subscribers to the channels?

Tags: node.js

I am fairly new at this. I am using Nodejs and Express linked to a mySQL database to build an application and now I need some library that allows that realtime messages are sent to the right users.

I have already tried socket.io but it was a little complicated for me to understand the documentation, so I searched for some other alternatives.
I found Mediator.js and I was trying to implement it in my server but now I am getting to the conclusion that I don't know how to make it work in real time.

- The website has an Admin and several normal users;
- The users can belong to groups (one, many or none) that the admin assigns.
- The Admin has to be able to send a string to the users that belong to a specific group if they are online - realtime.

**Is this possible to implement with mediator-js? Admin sends string to server and then server broadcasts to the members of the group that are online in realtime?
Or do I really have to use socket.io?**

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Looking at the [Mediator Pattern,](https://carldanley.com/js-mediator-pattern/) it seems like it might help you manage the complexity.  But you still need some kind of real-time communication mechanism.

Comment: So, if I use just mediator-js it means I won't be able to have the real-time communication I need?

Comment: It doesn't say anything on the mediator.js page about real-time communication.  Not the kind that socket.io provides, anyway.  mediator.js has a different purpose.  It's real-time if you make it real-time with something like socket.io.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am having a hard time at this because by reading socket.io's documentation I am not being able to implement it. I already managed to send messages in real-time client-server and server-client but i just can't get to filter to who the messages are going to.